# Count the number of Likes received by a user for all his posts - Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get the total number of likes given to a user which is in my case the `author` of the post.

I have commented my trial as it didn't work.

*Here is the models.py*

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author')
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='liked', blank=True)
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

*Here is the views.py that I have tried*

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "blog/post_detail.html" 

    def total_likes_received(request):
        #total_likes_received = Post.likes.filter(author=request.user).count() 
        return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'total_likes_received': total_likes_received})
```

*Here is the template:*

```
<small class="ml-5 mr-2" >Total {{ total_likes_received }} </small>
```

***Update:***
In order to try to fix this I have added:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "blog/post_detail.html"  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        total_likes_received = Post.likes.filter(author=self.request.user).count()
What should I add here to show the total likes of all posts of an author not the logged in user
        context['total_likes_received'] = total_likes_received
```

***My question is:***
How to get the total number of likes given for all the posts given to a particular author

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: it is not showing in the template. I will add the template to the question

Comment: you need to change Post.like.filter to Post.objects.filter

Comment: @Omar That would count the number of `Post`s, not likes.

Comment: you should have another model (Like) right? Like.objects.filter(author=request.user).count().

Comment: Try this: Post.objects.all().annotate(likes_count=Count('likes'), author=request.user)
Documentation link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should remove the `related_name='author'`, it is confusing. You should read the docs again to see what it actually means.

Comment: @ha-neul yes I have another Model Like but how is it going to get the total number of likes given to an author, I have added it incase it helps.

Comment: @Selcuk I have different models with users who have different roles, that is why I am using related name as author in the post model

Comment: @A_K I see that, but you are doing it wrong. `related_name` indicates the relation from the `User` to `Post`, so you should either name it `posts` or remove it to use the default one which is `post_set`. Also if you have a `Like` model you should declare it as a through model. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Comment: Try sth like: Like.objects.filter(post__author=request.user).count().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to get the post.author's all likes.

```
post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs['pk']) 
total_likes_received = Like.objects.filter(post__author=post.author).count()
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use the following query to do this.

```
all_posts = request.user.author.all()
total_likes_received = all_posts.aggregate(total_likes=Count('likes'))['total_likes']
```

Comment: I tried adding this code but I am getting `name 'request' is not defined`

Comment: I have added to my get_context_data it worked fine but it is showing the total likes received for the logged in user not the post details author because I am using def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):

Comment: I just tried to give you an idea, you need to integrate the rest according to your needs :)

Answer (score 1):

@A_K the problem is that you are using a DetailView, your code is good but badly used
the answer is simple and without changing your code do rather like this:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "blog/post_detail.html"

    def total_likes_received(self):
        total_likes_received = Like.objects.filter(post__author=post.author).count()
        return total_likes_received

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Insert the single object into the context dict."""
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['total_likes_received'] = self.total_likes_received()

        return context
```

Now Inside your template you don't have to change anything.

Comment: I added total_likes_received function but it returned `'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'filter'`

Comment: Ok a minute i update total_likes_received function to get you right

Comment: Ok refresh you page i show my new edition and try it

Comment: @A_K it's ok now ?

Comment: Actually this is returning the total no. of Posts made by an author

Comment: Yes you are right i have update my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply query like this:

```
total_likes_received = Like.objects.filter(post__author=self.request.user).count()
```

Comment: I have added to my `get_context_data` it worked fine but it is showing the total likes received for the logged in user not the post details author because I am using `def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):`